# Is there a way of getting all new values from a class?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a js web app that allows the user to create a list of good habits and a list of bad habits. Each day, the app randomly selects a good habit and a bad habit that the user must do/not do.

The functionality that allows the user to add and remove habits from the list is complete.

Is there a way that I could access all the new Goodhabit(goodHabit) I create? I need this so that I can assign them all a number to then randomly select one of the habits the user has to do.

Sample code:

```
class Goodhabit {
    constructor(goodHabit) {
        this.goodHabit = goodHabit;
    }
}

class UI {
    addGoodHabit(goodhabit) {
        // Get the html markup where the list will be shown
        const goodHabitList = document.getElementById('good-habit-list');

        // Create tr element
        const goodHabitRow = document.createElement('tr');

        // Insert html
        goodHabitRow.innerHTML = `
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>${goodhabit.goodHabit}</td>
            <td class="remove" id="remove">&#10005;</td>
        `;

        // Add row to list
        goodHabitList.appendChild(goodHabitRow);
    }

    // more code
});

// Event Listener For Adding A Good Habit

// Get button from html that allows user to add a good habit
document.getElementById('button-good-habit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Get form value
    const goodHabit = document.getElementById('good-habit').value;

    // Instantiate Good Habit
    const goodhabit = new Goodhabit(goodHabit);

    // Instantiate UI
    const ui = new UI();

    // more code
});
```

Comment: You should keep your data in an array, not in the DOM. Your `addGoodHabit` function should create the `GoodHabit` instance and store it somewhere so that you can access it.

Comment: Ok thanks I think that makes sense. Could you provide a code example that would be a great help?

Answer (score 0):

Does this works for you?

```js
const goodHabitList = [];
document.getElementById("good-habit-list")
  .querySelectorAll("td:not(.remove)")
  .forEach((elem) => goodHabitList.push(elem.textContent));

console.log(goodHabitList);
```